# Number of $r$-regular, triangle-free graphs of order 100

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I would like to find a formula for the number of $r$-regular, triangle free graphs of order 100 where every non-adjacent pair of adjacent vertices has $a$ common neighbors.

There is one special case which is quite well-known. This is the case $r=22$, the so called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%E2%80%93Sims_graph

Would be great if you have some idea.

Comment: The case $r=57$ has been open for 50 years. I do not think this is going to be easy.

Comment: Open cases under 400 nodes, in the format (nodes, $r$, $a$) are (176,25,4), (210,33,6), (266,45,9), (352,26,2), and (352,36,4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've described a [strongly regular graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StronglyRegularGraph.html). Brouwer has a list of 9 possible [100-node strongly regular graphs](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab51-100.html).

One has been proven impossible, seven exist.  One has unknown status. However, only the Higman-Sims graph has zero common neighbors for adjacent vertices (triangle free).  Therefore, it is the only strongly regular 100 node triangle free graphs.